# window.onbeforeunload allow submit button?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript to show a confirm box when a user leaves the page.

My problem is, it is showing even when user clicks the submit button inside a form in my page. I don't want this to be triggered on form submit and on a span click.

How can I allow form submit and span click in the function below?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;



    return '';
};
```

**EDIT**-------------------------------

sorry, it is now a form, it is simple button and a href:
I have one page that uses only a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" id="btn-crop" />
```

and a link:

```
<a href="done.php" class=button2>Save</a>
```

Comment: show code for form submit, also use `var`

Comment: @self in fact it is not a form, it is a button and a href link (I want to use this function in 2 pages)

Comment: I am sure there is a dupe. Either remove the listener or use a boolean that is set onsubmit

Comment: jsfiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/3hp5dczj/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check what object dispatched the event using e.currentTarget property and then show the prompt if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `[Event].stopPropagation` in an callback of submit event for each button in the page.

This function would stop the callback function of the `beforeunload` event when would go submit the button.

You can read more about the `[Event].stopPropagation` 
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Like so: `Button.addEventListener("submit",function(Event){Event.stopPropagation()})`

Comment: It will also stop the form submission.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah... I didn't understand well the question before. It's possible to call `submit` also (in form element).